# SCP using SSH config?

Tags: ssh, scp

I'm looking to SCP a file on a remote host which I usually would SSH into. I have a config file setup when I SSH which saves alot of time and typing. I'm trying to do something similar for SCP in that I want to copy a remote file locally but don't want to have to type the IP/host etc. Is that possible?

Trying to get this to work with SCP -F but also need to sub-verse out of my home directory...

Here's where I'm at, where myserver is the name of the host specified in the SSH config file.

```
scp -v -F myserver://var/www/html/file01/sampledir/329/619/myfile.mp4 /Users/Tony/Desktop
```

Comment: Where is the question? Does it work? If not, where does it fail?

Comment: Sorry, no it does not work - getting the below
    usage: scp [-1246BCEpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2[code]

Comment: Looks like you're feeding it an MP4 file as the ssh_config (-F)?? :)

Comment: I have it working on my system, as follows: scp remotehost:/home/myname/myfile . And it works. Drop the -F option, and you are ok.

Answer (score 6):

Just save the config file as `~/.ssh/config`, and it'll be used without the need for a `-F` flag.